# Rails: Cutting Down Code

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I know that I might have too much logic in my view, so I'm wondering how I can include it  in my controller:

Controller:

```
def purchasers
   @deal = Deal.find(params[:id])
   @pl = @deal.purchases
end
```

View:

```
<% title "List Of Purchases" %>
Total Purchases: <%= @pl.count %><BR><BR>
<%
@pl.each do |p|
    u = User.find(p.user_id)
    %>
    <%= u.email %><BR>
 <%
end
%>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd suggest that you remove the call to `User.find` inside the view code.

It looks like you're looking up the user from the `user_id` stored in the purchase. Why not in the model use:

```
class Purchase < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :user
   ...
end
```

And then in the view code:

```
<% @pl.each do |purchase| %>
  <%= purchase.user.email %><BR>
<% end %>
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you might not have set up your associations correctly in your Purchases and Users models. Instead of doing `u = User.find(p.user_id)` you should be able to write `p.user.email`, assuming that each `Purchase` `belongs_to :user`.

Answer (score 0):

if your Purchase model belongs to User model, you don't need to find User with User.find.
if not, belong your Purchase model to User model then

```
<% @pl.each do |p| %>
  <%= p.user.email %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

Its also worth noting the following can be improved to make use of Rails' skills when it comoes to caching collections:

```
<%= @pl.count %>
```

to

```
<%= @pl.size %>
```

The `size` method will return the number of purchases but won't load the objects into memory again as they have already been looked up in the controller.